# Memory Allocation for Recursive Functions

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, recursion

How is memory allocated when recursive functions are called?
A function has it's own allocated memory. When it is called, the parameters (not reference-passed ones) and variables get memory. So when the function is called again from within it's body, how is memory allocated to the variables and parameters of the second call?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A recursive function is no different from any other function--automatic local variables are allocated as a single block by advancing the stack pointer far enough to account for the sum of their sizes (plus any padding required for alignment).

Each recursive call pushes a new stack frame in that manner, then pops it when it returns.  If the recursion fails to reach a base case, the stack will rapidly be exhausted leading to the eponymous Stack Overflow crash.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a function recursively is done just like any other function. So the memory will be allocated the same way as if you are calling any regular function.

Comment: @Caesar:  Because it's essentially a non-answer.  You're correct that it's the same as any other type of function, but you stop short of explaining what that actually means.

Comment: @DrewHall It answers the question, if he needs to know how a regular function allocates memory then that is another question entirely.

Comment: @Caesar: Perhaps.  But I think inherent in the question is a lack of understanding of the mechanics of the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as calling any other function. The variables (not reference-passed ones) get allocated on the stack. When the functions start to return (i.e. base case is reached), the stack gets popped out in the order it was pushed to the stack over each nested recursive call.

This youtube video explains the call stack for recursive functions really well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0bb7UYy0pY

Comment: C++ does NOT guarantee that the automatically managed memory will be allocated on a stack like structure.

Comment: Like I said, the recursive function is treated like any other function, which is allocated on stack. If you'll look into the assembly, there will be a `PUSH` & `POP` operation. That has to be on a stack only. btw what do you mean by ` automatically managed memory` ?

Comment: While most automatically managed memory is handled using a stack, C++ does not guarantee that all systems must use a stack to store the memory.

Comment: I agree with your point there. But it is applicable for variables in a function. I think the discussion here is about the function stack. Although a variable might be allocated on a register but when another function is called, that variable has to be stored onto the stack, otherwise register is just a temporary placeholder, which the next function may use. Hence if the variable is stored on in a register, it has to be located on the function stackframe to preserve the value across function calls.

Answer (score 1):

When a function (call if `func1`) calls another function (call it `func2`), the data necessary for execution of `func2` is pushed on to the stack. That does not change for recursive functions (when `func2` is the same as `func1`).

If a recursive function gets called `10` times recursively, there will `10` stack frames, each corresponding to one invocation of the function.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is called, necessary params are pushed onto stack. When a function finishes its task, the params are poped out and program counter is restored.

There is no exception for recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters and local variables are allocated on the stack. They form a so-called [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). When a function is called recursively, a stack frame is allocated for each of the recursive call of the function.

E.g. if void f() is recursively called three times.

```
// Assume stack grows upwards
stack frame #3 <== the most recent call
stack frame #2
stack frame #1
```

Comment: C++ does NOT guarantee that the automatically managed memory will be allocated on a stack like structure.

Comment: I think it's de facto when recursion function is used. Why wouldn't it in this case?

Comment: @Caesar:  While it's true that the C++ standard does not use the word "stack" for this, the specified semantics of "automatic storage duration" and the mechanics of every major processor instruction set architecture (ISA) all but guarantee a stack will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Memory for automatic variables is allocated on [stack](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow2a.html). When you call another function (recursively self or some other), stack frames so far remain in their state, and we allocate more memory (let's say it like this) on stack to lodge the local variables of this new function. When the function ends, the new stack frame is discarded and we revert to previous (calee) stack frame.

You can play with any debugger of your choice to understand things even better. If you don't understand something, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

The Recurtion uses Stack memory to get executed

Go through the below example

```
void rev(Node* head){
if(head==NULL) return;
head=head->next;
rev(head);
cout<<head->data<<endl;}
```

Lets have a look in Stack Segment for recursion.

Let `NODE1 -> NODE2->NULL` Where NODE1 and NODE2 are struct objects.

What your function doing is:

```
Call to rev(NODE1)
Check if it is NULL
Point to next NODE i.e. NODE2

Call to rev(NODE2)

Check if It is NULL
Point to next NODE i.e. NULL

Call to rev(NULL)

Check if It is NULL
Pointer will be returned With head = NULL
```

Hope this will Help you.

Answer (score 1):

Functions (lines of code) you wrote are stored in text segment and when it is called it is allocated a frame in the stack memory, memory for variables (other than static) are also allocated in the stack in the given frame.

Recursive functions are no different its also normal functions which gets called n number of times. so its memory(frame) are also allocated on the stack n number of times.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is called it's parameters along other function states are saved on Stack.

Stack frame constructed during the function call contains the following:

- Function parameters.
- Function’s return address.
- Frame pointer.
- Exception Handler frame.
- Locally declared variables.
- Buffer.
- Callee save registers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to free the memory after using it.

Here is an example program that illustrates that.

http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?145311-Free-memory-or-garbage-in-recursion-program